# window.history vs. Router.history to go back

Tags: reactjs

Why would I ever use the Router history from `react-router-dom` over `window.history.back()`?

And is there a way of detecting if a user came from one of the pages in my app or from a **specific** external website and redirect him according to that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because. `window.history.back()` will just change the `url in the url bar` and reload the application and all the resources again but not `rerender the correct UI component` while Router history from `react-router-dom` sets the url plus render the `correct React component` based on the route.

**Second Part:** 
No. You can't detect from which external website user came to your app from as because of the **Security Reasons** [More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history#Notes).

While in your own app Yes. you can always detect if user navigated from one of the pages of your app by `window.onpopstate event` [usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate#The_popstate_event) .

Comment: Ok thanks! And what about the second part of my question? Is there a way of doing that?