# Why use useHistory goBack function instead of window history back function in React App?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

I implement page navigations with react-router.
When moving from B to A after moving from A to B, needs page back behavior.
Therefore, I wrote bellow.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

const history = useHisotry()

history.goBack();
```

It works well. But I have my doubts about it.
I can use `window.hisotry.back()` instead of `useHisotry() back`.

Why use useHistory goBack function instead of window history back function?

Comment: The answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540244 might explain although the question relates to react-router-dom, not react-router. But I guess it is pretty much same since react-router-dom is based on react-router.